# Finding coefficients using Sympy doesn't include square root (sqrt) as value

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, sqrt

In SymPy, there is a useful feature to create a dictionary of coefficients for a given expression.

However, I'm encountering an irritating bug (/feature?) whereby square roots are considered to be part of the variable, and not part of the coefficient value.

Minimum example:

```
from sympy import sqrt, symbols
k, t = symbols('k, t') 
d = 1.5*t + 2.5*sqrt(2)*k 
d.as_coefficients_dict()
```

This returns:

```
{:1.5, sqrt(2)*:2.5}
```

When instead, the sqrt(2) should be considered as part of the coefficient. Thus, I expected to see the result:

```
{:1.5, :2.5*sqrt(2)}
```

NB, I'm using the latest SymPy version 1.4

Is this a bug? Or an alternative way to use the function to get the expected value please?

EDIT: I amended the question to note that I am using the Sympy sqrt function. I also tried using NumPy's np.sqrt, which evaluates correctly, but gives the full numerical value rather than a nice neat sqrt(2) for the value of the k coefficient.

Comment: `from sympy import sqrt` I guess

Comment: I am using this already. Thanks for noting it though - I've amended the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.as_coefficients_dict) explicitly states:

> Return a dictionary mapping terms to their *Rational* coefficient.

So to start with, this is the expected behavior. To see this, you can note that the sqrt is *not* the problem, rather it is the fact that the coefficient is irrational. If we take a rational coefficient, we get your expected behavior:

```
>>> from sympy import sqrt, symbols
>>> k, t = symbols('k, t') 
>>> d = 1.5*t + 2.5*sqrt(4)*k 
>>> d.as_coefficients_dict()
{k: 5.00000000000000, t: 1.50000000000000}
```

One way to solve your problem is to explicitly inquire about each coefficient with the given variables:

```
>>> from sympy import sqrt, symbols
>>> k, t = symbols('k, t') 
>>> d = 1.5*t + 2.5*sqrt(2)*k 
>>> {sym : d.coeff(sym) for sym in (k, t)}  
{k: 2.5*sqrt(2), t: 1.50000000000000}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the expected behaviour. The workaround you posted works nicely thanks, although with the only limitation that I now need to explicitly specify the variables. This isn't a big issue though.